# how to get rid of PHP notice here?

Tags: php, notice

```
function t1()
{
  echo 1;
}
function t2()
{ 
  echo 2;
}

$funcs = array(t1,t2);

$length = count($funcs);
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
{
$funcs[$i]();
}
```

when I execute this tiny php file:

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant t1 - assumed 't1' in D:\jobirn\test\str.php on line 11

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant t2 - assumed 't2' in D:\jobirn\test\str.php on line 11

How can I get rid of those Notices?
12

Comment: I would close this as WORKSFORME

Comment: Really, I get no PHP NOTICE when I try to run your code. PHP 5.2.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a notice because PHP doesn't treat functions as first class objects.
When you do this

```
$functions = array(t1, t2);
```

The PHP engine sees t1, and t2, and tries to resolve it as a constant, but because it cannot find a constant named t1/t2, it "assumes" that you wanted to type array('t1', 't2');
If you do a var_dump($functions), you can see that the items in the array are strings.

When you try to call a string as a function, like

```
$functions[0]()
```

PHP will look for a function with the same name as the string. I wouldn't call this as using a string as a function pointer, this is more like using reflection. PHP calls it "variable functions", see:

http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

So, the correct way to get rid of the notices is:

```
$functions = array('t1', 't2');
```

About why does

```
't1'();
```

not work? Unfortunately there is no answer. It's PHP, there are a good number of these annoying as hell quirks. It's the same quirk as:

```
explode(':', 'one:two:three')[0];
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in php shell code on line 1
```

Edit:
The above mentioned array referencing syntax is available in PHP5.4, it's called array dereferencing.

Comment: your explanation is very clear,
but I still have a question,
why 't1'() is not treated the same as $s()?

Answer (score 6):

```
$funcs = array('t1','t2');
```

Unintuitive, but that's how it works

Comment: Expect a nicer behaviour in PHP 5.3 :)

Comment: that's really strange,

string can be used as a function?

but 't1'() will fail.

Could you explain this feature?why php has such a strange usage?

Comment: @Shore In PHP, you're not passing a function. You're just passing the name and executing it. var_dump($i) in your For loop and you will see that it's a string. $func[$i]() gets interpreted as (string)'t1'() which then is assumed to be the function call t1().

Bottom line: you can't store functions as variables in php

Comment: $s = 't1';
$s() and 't1'() should be the same thing,intuitively

Comment: They aren't.  Pay attention, Shore.  You pass the name of the function and when the variable is called as a function the string name is associated with the method.  This is just the way it is: you never write `'t1'()` when you mean `t1()`, which is why `$var()` works.

Comment: Shore: Strings are not objects in PHP. So a string variable and string constant can and do act differently in the syntax of the language. There is no other explanation. PHP also lacks a lot of syntactic sugar as WishCow points out with the inability to say: func_with_array_result()[3].

Comment: Or to think about it another way, when you do $s='t1', the value of the variable is not 't1' but just the two letters, t1. When you use $s() you are replacing $s with the string t1, not 't1' with the apostrophes. Therefore, 't1'() is the same as $s='\'t1\''; $s() if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The work-round to this issue is to change the php.ini settings from

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: While this works, it's *hiding* the notices, not *fixing* the issue.

Comment: Notices are not issues, they're "better safe than sorry"-style messages for things that *could possibly be* mistakes but not necessarily.  Therefore, in the case of notices (not warnings and above!), it's an acceptable thing to say "okay I got this, don't warn about this one in the future".  It's also acceptable to completely disable notices, and only switch it on when you want to proofread your code for some rare reason.  In general, notices rarely save you but a lot of times you have to do painful & inefficient workarounds to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the error_reporting() function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

It lets you configure what level of errors, notices and warnings are displayed.

For example, if you want errors and warnings and no notices:

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING);

Answer (score 0):

Use [string declarations](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) if you mean strings:

```
$funcs = array('t1','t2');
```

See also the [chapter on varaible functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: I don't think the OP meant this, because he clearly calls the functions later with: $funcs[$i]()

Comment: I think it's essentially :

string variables can be used as function pointer,

I didn't notice this before,

and I have no idea why php implements such a strange usage,

can you explain to me so that I may think it makes sense?

Answer (score -1):

to use strings to call a function, you should use curly braces

```
'hello'() // wont work
$hello = 'hello'; $hello() // will work
```

edit it seems {''}() doesnt work. i remember it used to >.<

Comment: "{'hello'}()" Does not work on PHP 5.2.8:
php -r '{"phpinfo"}();' fails with "Syntax error, unexpected '}'"